# Duplicidade com JOIN

Tags: query, join

Olá, preciso de uma ajuda, se puderem me ajudar, agradeço.

Preciso fazer uma query entre três tabelas, no entanto, quando faço a busca a query está me retornando linhas duplicadas:

```
SELECT US.NOME AS PROFISSIONAL, AG.NOMEPACIENTE AS NOME_PACIENTE, CONV.NOME 
AS CONVENIO, AG.NUMEROPRONTUARIO, AG.DATA,
P.CODIGOAMB AS DESCRICAO_ATENDIMENTO, P.TOTALTAXAS AS TOTAL_TAXAS, 
P.TOTALDIARIAS AS TOTAL_DIARIA
FROM T_AGENDACONSULTAS AS AG
JOIN T_USUARIOS AS US ON AG.USUARIO = US.CODIGO
JOIN T_CONVENIOS AS CONV ON AG.CONVENIO = CONV.CODIGO
JOIN T_PACIENTESCONTAS AS P ON AG.NUMEROPRONTUARIO = P.PACIENTE
WHERE DATA BETWEEN '2019/06/01' AND '2019/06/30' AND NOMEPACIENTE='augusto prazeres'
```

Comment: Experimenta colocar Select Distinct  depois seus campos

Comment: Se a resposta serviu, marque como certa

Answer (score 2):

```
  SELECT DISTINCT US.NOME AS PROFISSIONAL, AG.NOMEPACIENTE AS NOME_PACIENTE,
         CONV.NOME AS CONVENIO, AG.NUMEROPRONTUARIO, AG.DATA, P.CODIGOAMB AS
         DESCRICAO_ATENDIMENTO, P.TOTALTAXAS AS TOTAL_TAXAS, P.TOTALDIARIAS AS
         TOTAL_DIARIA
    FROM T_AGENDACONSULTAS AS AG JOIN T_USUARIOS AS US ON AG.USUARIO = US.CODIGO 
         JOIN T_CONVENIOS AS CONV ON AG.CONVENIO = CONV.CODIGO
         JOIN T_PACIENTESCONTAS AS P ON AG.NUMEROPRONTUARIO = P.PACIENTE
   WHERE DATA BETWEEN '2019/06/01'
         AND '2019/06/30' AND NOMEPACIENTE='augusto prazeres'
```